# Auto updates OPC server

Tags: c#, configuration, updates, opc

I have a C# source code for OPC server.
The code is working and I connect successfully but I have one big problem,
the data auto update does not work, in other words, I need to restart the server so it will
take the new data from the data base.

The code has an attribute named "updatePiriod", initialaized to 60000 ms and still, no auto updates.

Answer (score 1):

There's more to getting data updates than simply connecting to the server. Have you 1) Created a Group; 2) Created items; 3) Activated the items; 4) Subscribed to callbacks?